# Multiple controllers but single create form - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have an existing invoicing inventory tracking application that I need to refactor.

We need to create single form for creating. Depending on the selected type, we have to show some fields for a certain type in the creation form and hide them for others.

Previous developers have created separate forms for each type, and the same input form code is repeated over and over for each type of document. The code is huge and hard to maintain and i must fix it and make simpler.

The application has tables `document_type` and `document`.

**The document type table contains document types such as:**

1. Invoice
2. Pro-invoice
3. Offer
4. Customer order
5. Order to the supplier
6. Internal warehouse transfer
7. Invoice from wholesale

Each type contains almost the same fields in the form, only in some types we have to hide the field for supplier input, warehouse selection, price input etc...

We want to use single form for create this data. Based on selected document_type show specific fields for invoice but for Offer hide some fields showed in Invoice.

My question Is it better to create a separated controller for each document type where i will pass document_type_id and in blade determine what filed will be showed.
Or create field collection for all document types ?

1. Create InvoiceController, ProInvoiceController, OfferController etc...
2. In each controller define document type_id
3. Create unique form where i will handle

Example

```
<?php

class InvoiceController extens Controller
{
   private $this->document_type = 4; // Invoice type

   public function crate()
   {
      $invoices = Document::where('document_type_id', $this->document_type)->get();
        
      // etc..

      return view('admin.document.index',[
                'title' => 'Invoice',
                'invoices' => $invoices,
       ]);
        
    }

// other controllers
class OfferController extens Controller {}
class ProInvoiceController extens Controller {}

?>
```

**Form.blade.php**

```
<!-- Invoice-->
@if($document_type_id == 1)
  
  <input type="text" name="customer">
  <input type="text" name="price">
  <select type="text" name="delivery_id"></select>


<!-- Offer -->
@elseif($document_type_id == 2)
  <input type="text" name="comercial_customer">
  <input type="text" name="price">
  <select type="text" name="delivery_id"></select>

<!--  Internal warehouse transfer -->
@elseif($document_type_id == 2)
  <select type="text" name="wharehouse_from_id"></select>
  <select type="text" name="wharehouse_from_to"></select>

@else
<!-- Show default -->

@endif
```

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: This is a personal preference I believe; in my opinion one controller and a collection of fields is better because of less code & only thing which changes is fields list

Comment: So only one DocumentCntroller and in blade check which is type then show specific field? Each type have different route i forgot to say that

Comment: I would write some helper function or some class, like `getDocumentFields(int $documentTypeID): array`, so those method will return needed fields array like `[['type' => 'input', 'type' => 'text', 'name' => 'customer'], ['type' => 'input', 'type' => 'text', 'name' => 'price'],...]` and then in blade just showing fields by @foreach; or method could be a html constructor which will return html for those fields

Answer (score 0):

Rather than document type, I would create an array of required field sections in each controller and then show/hide the relevant form sections in a single form template.

You can pass the array of fields to the view, or you can pass reference to the controller to the view;

```
return view('view.name')->withController($this);
```

Then in the view, access any controller properties or methods.

I would also have the same form for edit and create then use $model->exists() to test if this is a create or edit form so that the form route and method can be adjusted accordingly (see https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers) where passing an empty model to the view simplifies CRUD forms considerably.